Setting Ethernet PHY to transmission only
I'm working on a project where I have an FPGA and I'm using its Ethernet PHY to periodically transmit data to a connected device via an Ethernet cable. I have some code to do so, but I'm not seeing any packets being received. The FPGA board I'm using is the Nexys 4 DDR. I suspect that my issue may be with how I'm handling the MDIO registers, as I'm extremely new to them. How exactly would I need to set these registers to simply have transmission only? I currently have an interframe gap of 48 cycles, and a packet length of 66 bytes. The register mapping for the PHY is this:

As it stands, I set TXEN to high during transmission and low during the IFG. Reset is an active low, so I set it to low during the first 100000 cycles and then to high. I mainly need to know what to set MDIO and MDC to to get the transmission only config. I'm using a LAN8720A PHY.
I found this table in the spec:

Which mode here is optimal?

You don't need to set it to transmit only. You can ignore reception with a full duplex link. But you likely need to set the mode bits correctly even before reset, the board may do that for you with the resistors. Generally a simple PHY needs no MDIO control, and will negotiate link up automatically. As long as strap pins are set to do that. And the clock is correct.

@Justme Thanks, that makes sense. Do I need to be cycling my tx_enable signal or can I just keep it high throughout the transmission period of my frame?
